Why is my counter variable counting infinite times
I'm using Tensorflow to track the number of reps a user does a bicep curl. Every time I curl my bicep, instead of the counter incrementing once, it keeps counting until I stop doing a bicep curl. The count reps function is crucial to show the user how many reps they have done so far. The function extracts the points from the shoulder, elbow, and wrist and it finds the angle to determine if a user is doing a bicep curl. I would do one bicep curl, but the longer I hold it, the more it keeps counting. I'm not sure why this is happening. Can someone help.
    const webcamRef = useRef(null);
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const [pose, setPose] = useState(null);
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [stage, setStage] = useState('down');
    const [angle, setAngle] = useState(0);
    const [canCount, setCanCount] = useState(true);

const countReps = (pose) => {
        const confidenceThreshold = 0.35; // Set a confidence threshold
        const leftShoulder = pose.keypoints.find(point => point.part === 'leftShoulder' && point.score > confidenceThreshold);
        const leftElbow = pose.keypoints.find(point => point.part === 'leftElbow' && point.score > confidenceThreshold);
        const leftWrist = pose.keypoints.find(point => point.part === 'leftWrist' && point.score > confidenceThreshold);
    
        if (leftShoulder && leftElbow && leftWrist) {
            const angle = calculateAngle(leftShoulder.position, leftElbow.position, leftWrist.position);
            setAngle(angle); 
    
            if (angle > 140) {
                setStage('down');
                setCanCount(true);
                console.log('Stage changed to down');
            } else if (angle < 40 && stage === 'down') {
                setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1);
                setCanCount(false); // Prevent counting until the next down
                setStage('up');
                console.log('Stage changed to up');
                
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Key points not detected or not confident enough");
        }
    };


You will need to [edit] your question with more details. How is countReps being used? That seems to be critical explaining the problem you're describing

@BrianThompson Just edited it. Let me know if that provides more clarification?

Maybe it's because I don't know tensorflow, but I still don't see enough information to help. You have state hooks, but haven't included the full React component. It seems like countReps is being called multiple times while you hold down a button? But without seeing any code detailing how you're using (or passing) countReps, I don't think this is answerable

@BrianThompson I see, I'm not able to paste the full code but this is the repo: https://github.com/laura-nguyen/flexifit-ai/blob/main/src/components/Test/Test.jsx

Ok, so your countReps function is running once every .1 seconds and checking via a video feed processed by tensorflow if a rep has been completed, and the problem is when the rep is at full contraction for longer than .1 seconds it continues to increment as if it were another full rep. Is that correct?

@BrianThompson yes that's correct
